# When closing form I get An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#

Additional Information: Cannot access a disposed object.
And it highlights this line of code:

```
 if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new TelemetryData(Telemetry_Data), new object[2] {data, updated});
            return;
        }
```

This happens when I try to exit my application and throws this exception. Not sure what code you guys need to help me figure this out but here is my onClosing code:

```
 private void FleetTrack_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblFTstatus.Text == "CONNECTED")
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("You are currently connected to FleetTrack™\n\nIf you exit now, you will lose all progress on this job.",
                "Exit FleetTrack™", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                dbConnect.Delete();
                Application.ExitThread();
            }
            else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
        else if (lblFTstatus.Text == "DISCONNECTED")
        {
            Application.ExitThread();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a background thread attempting to marshal over to the GUI thread via `Invoke`.  You close the form but the background thread continues running.  The form is disposed of when `Invoke` is called so you get an `ObjectDisposedException`.

The dirty "fix" is to catch the exception.  Since you're closing you may not care.  But the real fix is to shut down your background threads before the form closes.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to reply. I really appreciate it. I'm still new to C#, is there an example out there of how to close the backround thread before the form closes you can reference for me?

Comment: That depends on how the thread is running.  If you post the code for the background thread I can help more.  For example, if you're using the TPL (a `Task`) you can use a `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: Like I said, I am new to this. I've integrated an open source SDK into my code that was pre-written to get data values from a PC game. Not sure where/what code is related to the background thread. I did do the dirty fix. But if you still want to help me do the real fix, I may need a little help getting the code you need, haha. Sorry for my n00b-ness.

Comment: Sure.  Another thing you can do is check if `IsDisposed` is true before doing an `Invoke`.  This isn't perfect but can avoid some of the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Frm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Application.ExitThread();
}
```

Close thread using this.